# Can I install an IPA on my iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

After submitting my app to the app store, i created a zip of all of it's files. Now i'm on the next release, I want to test with the previous version to ensure that updating works properly, as there's some structural changes. Unfortunately, some files were referenced, but not copied, and so they have since been either deleted or modified.

Without being able to build again from the project, is there any way I could install the previous version on my phone?

Comment: If you drop the IPA to iTunes, it will be installed when you sync.

Comment: Doing a search of the files for .IPA doesn't return any results. Where is this usually located?

Comment: Didn't you write you had the previous version of the app?

Comment: I zipped all of the files, but typing .IPA into finder doesn't show the IPA, and searching around i can't seem to find it, or a build folder.

Comment: if you zipped the files, then put all the resources (images, whatever), `Info.plist` and the executable along with the generated code signature in an `.app` bundle, add it to a folder called `Payload` and zip it, rename to `.ipa`, voila, you have a valid IPA.

Answer (score 1):

Open Xcode -> Archives, select your target archive, distribute -> Ad-hoc Deployment, save the .ipa file and drag it into iTunes.

If you want to send the .ipa to others, the ad-hoc provision file is needed too.

Comment: That is not what he asked for.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is simply to delete the new version of the app from your iPhone, then install the old one from the iTunes App Store. If you want to run both at once, temporarily change the bundle identifier for the new version and then install it via Xcode.

Comment: That's fine for now, but is it possible to download the old version from the app store and then install it from that version later? Once I make future updates, I want to go back to various version and test with them.

Comment: Yes, just synch your iPhone with iTunes, and then copy the IPA from iTunes to somewhere safe from the default location (as described here: http://osxdaily.com/2011/12/15/where-ios-apps-stored-locally-in-mac-os-x-and-windows/). Than you can simply drag the IPA on to your iTunes Library and re-sync at any time in the future when you want to re-install that version.

Answer (score 0):

Archive different versions of the app that will create IPA files. Then drop the provisioning profile and IPA files in ITunes and install it from there.